# Display time as "12:00 noon" instead of "12:00 pm"

Tags: date-time, timezones

We display event dates/times via Wordpress [date and time](https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/) functions in am/pm time (12 hour, not 24 hour). For any times that are noon - i.e. "12:00 pm" - we'd like to display "12:00 noon" instead.

And we'd also like to display "12:00 midnight" instead of "12:00 am".

This is to avoid confusion (we run online events around the world at different times so there is room for this type of confusion).

All other times of the day can keep their am/pm, it's just these two exact times that we're seeking to change.

Comment: The best way to do this would be to replace the `am` and `pm` using jQuery - can you post your output code so we can see if there's something that can be targeted via the functionality? I've done something similar by replacing 'months' with 'seasons' but you have to be able to target an element and replace the text.

Comment: Oh I see, you mean [like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324559/jquery-if-div-contains-this-text-replace-that-part-of-the-text) I've tried that but I can't get it right. The page in question we're trying to change is [here](https://www.aetherius.org/online-services-v2/)

Comment: Might be having a hard time with it because the selection process is pretty ambiguous.  Are you able to add to the template that generates the content for those entries?  Then wrap the time in something simple like `<span class="pp-time">12:00 pm</span>`?

Comment: Ok did that, and have now got this script: `$(".tas-event-time").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("pm", "noon"); 
});`

Comment: You don't want to target all `pm` instances though, just those that start at 12:00, correct?

Comment: Yes but it's not even doing it with just that

Comment: I was testing my answer and have posted it.  If I put it into the console, just this line `$( '.tas-event-time' ).html( $( '.tas-event-time' ).html().replace( '12:00 pm','12:00 noon') );` it executes perfectly and changes 12:00pm to 12:00 noon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need to do is make your life easier and instead of searching everything within every instance of `.pp-post-content` or `.pp-post-content p`, let's wrap the times or the times in question with a span tag.  Like you suggested in your comments `<span class="tas-event-time">` is sufficient enough.

Now, in your .js file, you want to add the following:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    $( '.tas-event-time' ).html( $( '.tas-event-time' ).html().replace( '12:00 pm','12:00 noon') );
} );
```

That will, once the document is ready, change the instances of *'12:00 pm'* to *'12:00 noon'*.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Do it with Translation loops! Simply find the "12:00 pm" and put 12:00 Noon. Maybe It works! try it :D.